# how to set json tag with a variable in golang?

Tags: json, go

is there a way to set field tag of a struct ?
for example :

```
type contact struct {
    Mail string `json:"contact"`
}

newStruct := setTag(temp, "Mail", "mail")

data, _ := json.Marshaller(qwe)
fmt.Println(data)
```

and it accepts this payload:

```
{
    "mail": "blabla"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct JSON content type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want your key of the json to be a variable. You can do this by using the [map](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16) data type.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    asd := "mail"
    qwe := make(map[string]string)

    qwe[asd] = "jack"

    data, _ := json.Marshal(qwe)
    fmt.Println(string(data))  // Prints "{mail: jack}"
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/a2O_TvNImh)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the key. [Working example](http://play.golang.org/p/xT_mk_6s0I)

From [godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for package json.Marshal,

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field
> becomes a member of the object unless
>
> - the field's tag is "-", or
> - the field is empty and its tag specifies the "omitempty" option.